# Python code to play an audio file

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want to build a school alarm application using python and raspberry pi.

How can i use use python to play an audio file at specified timings?

Comment: This is....just tremendously broad; have you put any effort at all into this project? 

Have you tried setting it to wumbo?

Comment: i know that base code to play an audio file like s = Sound() 
s.read('sound.wav') 
s.play(), but i want this to play at a specified time, which i am not sure of.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if the alarm noise file is in the same directory as the python file itself. I do warn you though this is very clunky and the sound file is opened separately but nevertheless it does what you required.

```
import os, time

while True:
    os.startfile("FILENAME OF SOUND") #Replace with the appropriate file name (Make sure the alarm sound is in the same directory as the python file else this will not work)
    time.sleep(DELAY IN SECONDS) #This is how long the delay is between each time it opens the sound
```